# Unable to compile XINU source code after adding a new function in assembly language

Tags: c, x86, operating-system, header-files, xinu

I have added a file function.S in sys folder in XINU.

```
   .text
   .globl zfunction

zfunction:
<x86 code>
```

equivalent C code for this function is

```
long zfunction(long param)
{

  long mask = 0xfff803dd ;
  param &= mask  ;

  param = (param << 4) & 0xffffffff;

  return param;
}
```

I need to use the function in zfunction.S in main function. How do I create a header file that links an assembly level code to C program? If I add
    extern int long zfunction(param) in the header file, make fails with the error

```
main.o(.text+0x1e): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `zfunction'
make: *** [xinu.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: Double check that: a) everything gets compiled/assembled and linked together b) you respected any eventual name mangling.

Comment: @sank did you get it resolved? could you share what went wrong if so?